# How to count occurences in a list column on postgres?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by, count

I've a table with the following structure:

```
user  |  medias
----------------------
 1    | {ps2,xbox}
 1    | {nintendo,ps2}
```

How do i count the occurrences of each string in an array column?

Expected result:

```
media    |  amount
------------------
ps2      |    2
nintendo |    1
xbox     |    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unnest the array with a lateral join, then aggregate:

```
select x.media, count(*) amount
from myable t
cross join lateral unnest(t.medias) x(media)
group by x.media
order by amount desc, x.media
```